# Angular HTTP Interceptor not setting header

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I am not getting any errors, and am able to set the authToken value from my login component with a valid token (that I have verified with Postman).  But I do not get any Authorization parameter added to my request header.

```
 entryComponents: [
    ConfirmDialogTargetComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthInterceptor,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true     
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

```
import { Injectable }                                               from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest }     from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable }                                               from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor {

    authToken: string = '';

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        const authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authToken) });
        return next.handle(authReq);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to debug and set a break point in the intercept method? Are you using the HttpClientModule and not HttpModule?

Comment: I am using HttpModule - is this correct?

Comment: from app.module

import { HttpModule }  from '@angular/http';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: If you are using the Http class instead of the HttpClient class to make requests, then you mixed the APIs

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first AuthInterceptor:

```
 entryComponents: [
    ConfirmDialogTargetComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true     
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: unfortunately I tried that and it does not help.  It's there because the login component imports it so that it can set the authToken value inside the AuthInterceptor service.  If I remove the first instance of AuthInterceptor in the providers array then the login component errors.